# Splitting camelcase paths at uppercase letters in Linux

Tags: linux, split, camelcasing

Working in a linux tcsh shell I'd like to echo a camelcase directory name, in lower case, with the separate parts of the name split up e.g in my PWD, `iWantToSplitThisUp >> i want to split this up`.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $dirname | sed -e 's/\([a-z]\)\([A-Z]\)/\1 \2/g' | tr A-Z a-z
```